# Replicating mcrypt_encrypt in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, angular, encryption

I am unable to reproduce this function and result in JS.

```
<?php
 //Some padding
 $result = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "1234567890123456", padded("plainText"),MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)
 $res = base64_encode($result)
 ....
```

I have tried crypto js, js-mcrypt in angular 6

```
const result = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("plainText", "1234567890123456", {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

Comment: Just a heads up, `mcrypt` was considered abandonware pretty much on the date it was released and there's good reasons for that (which is why it's been removed in newer versions of PHP). Replicating it might not be exactly a good thing to do.

Comment: Is it because the php result is base 64 and the javascript is hex?.

Comment: @DaveCarruthers base64 gives an error, run time error so keeping it hex for the example

Comment: Read: [If You're Typing the Word **mcrypt** Into Your PHP Code, You're Doing It Wrong](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong)